# Why Google Apps Script throwing an "internal error" for Sites Services?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

Here is my script, which basically iterate through drive folder, and put the file's blob as a attachment to some page on google site. It was working fine till day before yesterday, suddenly stop working after that.

```
function myFunction() {
  var testpage = SitesApp.getSiteByUrl(siteURL).getChildByName("test");
  var photofolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder_ID);
  var filesinpf = photofolder.getFiles();
  while(filesinpf.hasNext()){
    var file = filesinpf.next();
    var fblob = file.getBlob();
    testpage.addHostedAttachment(fblob); //This line generating an error
  }
}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem yesterday.
I have been working with this for a week, and yesterday I got an internal error in the last line:

```
 function myFunction() {

   var myFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById                      
   ("0B-ZOMOQnNEDOU9sWEV5SzlXVTQ");
  var myFile = 
  myFolder.getFilesByName("Data.txt").next();
  var myBlob = myFile.getBlob();

  var myPage = 
 SitesApp.getSiteByUrl("https://sites.google.com/site/  
 demo ").getChildByName 
 ("home/demoFileCabinet");

  myPage.addHostedAttachment(myBlob);
 }
```

Maybe a problem in Google Sites??. The code is correct.

I created an Issue Tracker too.

Comment: Yes! It seems to be their internal problem.

Comment: Bufff, I use this kind of scripts in my job :-(, I hope they solve the problem quickly

Comment: Hopefully! Thanks !

Comment: Any news about the enterprise support Ticket?

Comment: I don't know!. I moved to the new thing as of now!

Answer (score 0):

You can reproduce this error by using the sample code provided by google:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/page#addHostedAttachment(BlobSource)

I created an enterprise support Ticket.

Keep you updated: [Case #14128120] Google Sites addHostedAttachment() not working

Answer (score 0):

I got the following response from google:

Let me confirm that this is an issue on our end, filed with issue ID #68842220.

Please notice that our Engineering Team has already found the root cause for this.
At the moment, still, I can't confirm you when it will be fixed, but let me provide you with a simple workaround that will work while we wait for the fix: swap the "domain.com" and the "macros" parts of the URL when entering the URL in the dialog.

Sample, for url:

```
https://script.google.com/a/domain.com/macros/s/AKfycbwJfGpXIiWHfsCi-j66RuPMNx6kTFsdjYIbNOyufZptGA1tirm6/exec
```

try

```
https://script.google.com/a/macros/domain.com/s/AKfycbwJfGpXIiWHfsCi-j66RuPMNx6kTFsdjYIbNOyufZptGA1tirm6/exec
```